# grep for x # of lines following match from particular session

Tags: grep, sh

how do i use shell to grep for particular session, error and everything else following error but not other session.

here is example:

```
Mon Jun  6 14:19:12 2011 (1307369952): Received from  10.25.68.106; Session:48090
Message   : 0x300 (NDMP_TAPE_OPEN)
Timestamp : 1307369953
XSequence : 6
RSequence : 0
Error     : 0 (NDMP_NO_ERR)
    Device : tape016
    Mode : 0 (Read Only)
```

i want to grep Session:48090 and error, device and mode of this session using shell. 
so my output should be:

```
Error     : 0 (NDMP_NO_ERR)
Device : tape016
Mode : 0 (Read Only)
```

Thanks,
-Brian

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-A` parameter to include the next 7 lines following a match, and then `tail` to get the last 3 lines of that output. Example:

```
grep -A 7 "Session:48090" file | tail -n 3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know exactly how many lines there are after your "Session" line, but you do know that you need "Error", "Device", and "Mode", you can do this:

```
sed -ne '/Session:48090/,/Session:/{/^[        ]*Error/p;/^[        ]*Device/p;/^[        ]*Mode/p}' your.file
```

Inside each of those square brackets is a space and a tab.